# Seedborn Muse & Sands of Time on the stack

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If an opponent has [Seedborn Muse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSeedborn%20Muse%5d) out in play, I cast [Sands of Time](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSands%20of%20Time%5d), then the opponent's turn comes back around.
How would the stack resolve between these two cards on their turn? 
Does Sands of Time trigger resolve first or does Seedborn Muse? Or does the opponent pick which happens first since both trigger onto the stack at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

Sands of Time makes everyone skip their untap step.  Period.  It is a continuous effect, it doesn't trigger.  Seedborn Muse will do nothing in this scenario as there are no untap steps during which to untap it's controller's permenants.

Answer (score 4):

**Seedborn Muse would have no effect, because Seedborn Muse modifies the untap step, but Sands of Time makes all players skip their untap step.**

The ability of Seedborne Muse is a static ability that modifies the rules of the game. It does not trigger and does not go on the stack. It just modifies how the untap step would play out, by making you untap during every player's untap step instead of just your own.

The first ability of Sands of Time is also a static ability. It creates a replacement effect.

> 614.1b Effects that use the word “skip” are replacement effects. These replacement effects use the word “skip” to indicate what events, steps, phases, or turns will be replaced with nothing.

Whenever an untap step would occur for any player, the game instead goes into the upkeep step. The untap step simply doesn't happen.

It doesn't matter that Seedborn Muse modifies the untap step, because that step simply doesn't happen. Even if Seedborn Muses's ability was a triggered ability, it still wouldn't happen because the trigger event (untap step) doesn't happen.

Therefore, Sands of Time completely nullifies Seedborn Muse's ability.

Answer (score 2):

[Sands of Time](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSands%20of%20Time%5d) has 2 separate abilities; the first is not a triggered ability, but a continuous ability that creates a replacement effect:

> 614.1b Effects that use the word “skip” are replacement effects. These replacement effects use the word “skip” to indicate what events, steps, phases, or turns will be replaced with nothing.

The replacement effect replaces "Untap step" with "nothing". Because the Untap step never happens; [Seedborn Muse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSeedborn%20Muse%5d) will simply not do anything at all; there is no untap step during which its ability would get to be used.

Also, even if Sands of Time did keep the untap step around and simply change what happens during the untap step; it would not interaction with Seedborn Muse. This is because Sands of Time only changes what happens to a player on their own turn; it does not do anything to you if it isn't your turn. Seedborn Muse only affects you on your opponent's turn; it doesn't do anything at all during your own turn. So if Sands of Time were worded the way you seem to have interpreted it; then on your own turns you would do the Sands of Time tap-switching effect; and on your opponent's turns you would simply untap all permanents you control.